# Teams Bot SSO and TeamsLogon.aspx

Tags: botframework, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I have a Teams query messaging extension with SSO. SSO and extension works well. The adaptive cards that I return have actions, but one of the actions is to open a SharePoint component that requires TeamLogon.aspx redirect to use. TeamsLogon.aspx requires specific SharePoint webApplicationInfo, e.g. ("id": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", "resource": "https://tenant.sharepoint.com"), but I already have my custom config for SSO to work. Are there any workarounds for such a situation yet?

Comment: Hi @Saulius, we are looking into it , will get back to you soon

Comment: Hi @Saulius, are you using same tenant or different tenants for this.

Comment: Hi @Jagadeesh-MSFT, thanks for coming back. It is on the same tenant.

Answer (score 0):

If your bot has SSO credentials for app A then you can't open app B and expect SSO to work. We have restriction on one SSO credentials per app manifest.

Comment: yes, I know, but I see this very common case on messaging extensions to have SSO with your bot and opening actions from adaptive cards to do something on SharePoint, e.g. some custom web part. I would expect TeamsLogon.aspx page to have built-in silent SSO with SharePoint, and not to be dependent on "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000".